# Remove drilled out venturi tube from base in thermador gas range?

Tags: stove

When this stove was serviced a few years ago, the tech had to drill out one or two venturi tubes.

I just had to drill out 2 of 4 in order to remove the top of the stove. They were completely siezed up.

So... the top of the stove is off... but how do I get the remains of these venturi tubes out of the threaded base?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I did it.

Here is how:

Remove the jet holder from the stove, put it in a vise (gently)

Insert spiral bolt extractor. Tap it in with two hammer taps.

Attach socket to end of bolt extractor. Use electric impact wrench, short bursts, and break it free.

Was able to remove three of four no problem. The fourth was frozen completely, and I will replace the whole thing.

Answer (score -1):

Is the remaining portion of the tube a soft metal like brass? Even if it was steel I would think that you could use some strong pliers to get ahold of the upper edge and start to bend it inward. doing so would start to free the metal from the base it was screwed into and possibly even getting it to the point it would be able to turn.

Try the bending process so as to get as much of the sidewall to bend inwards as possible. Here is as attempt at a pictorial guide:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But that approach did not fly. These things get really hot (over and over and over) and the metal really seizes up. I am trying to figure out what anti-seize to use, so that the stove remains more servicable over time. (Conventional silver metallic anti seize is not doing the trick, sadly)